# Heading Text and Icon Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to align my `heading` tag text and font awesome icon in the correct places inside my navigation bar. When my navigation bar expands, I wish for the `heading` text (sidenav-heading) and icon (sidenav-expand) to be on the same line, while the `heading` text is on the left (as it is) and the icon on the right (as it is). My code:

```js
let sidenav = document.getElementById("sidenav");
sidenav.onmouseover = function() {
  //expandNav();
  sidenav.style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.add("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "right";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "inline-block";
};
sidenav.onmouseout = function() {
  //closeNav();
  sidenav.style.width = "75px";
  document.getElementById("expand-icon").classList.remove("expand");
  document.getElementById("sidenav-expand").style.textAlign = "center";
  document.getElementById("sidenav-heading").style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#sidenav-heading {}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
}

.expand {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidenav">
    <div id="sidenav-brand">
      <div id="sidenav-heading" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Expanded</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="sidenav-expand">
        <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidenav-links"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

AND a jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/khean52w/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/z9qepbc7/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update #sidenav-brand class as follows, it should work:

```
#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 10px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works however, the icon before the nav is expanded, is now off center and extra padding is added to the sidebar-brand when expanded. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Please try this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/z9qepbc7/13/